# Refactoring database with JSON content on liquibase

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, liquibase

I am working with a Java Spring application + hibernate + relational database (Edit: we have to support Postgresql, MySql and Oracle).

Some of our tables stores Objects serialized as JSON.

We use liquibase to manage our changes but, when it comes to changes that affect those JSONs, we don't know what to do.

How would you go about refactoring this type of datasets?

Imagine I serialize this POJO:

```
class POJO {
    String name
    Date   someDate
    Double someDouble
...
```

Then we change it:

```
class POJO {
    String name
    Date   someDateButAnotherName
    String aNewField
    //Double someDouble  <-- deleted
...
```

How could I migrate this scenario?

Comment: If you mean serializing to Serializable, you can implement Serializable and implements serializeObject so it skip the deleted field.

Something similar can be done if you doing JSON

Answer (score 2):

JSON serialization is a DB vendor specific feature so it is not supported by Liquibase xml syntax. What you can do is native sql using `<sql>` tag.

Then if you're storing your serialized object as PostgreSQL jsonb type using [PostgreSQL json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html).

If you're storing it as plain string you would have to do [string manipulations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html) that would be more tricky.

Comment: We have to support Postgresql, MySql and Oracle (possibly anything the client wants).